# SQL: HAVING on conditional SUM

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I've built a query to compare a company's sale stats to other companies.

Simplified, it's like:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN company=foobar THEN sales ELSE 0) as sales_foobar,
SUM(sales) as sales_total, country, year, product FROM sales_table
GROUP BY country, year, product HAVING (the above sum again) > 0
```

A compliance rule requires that only rows may be shown where the company had any sales and while my code will discard rows where foobar had no sales, it will also drop these where sales are 0 due to orders and refunds beeing equal.

Now, how could i achieve getting only rows where the company had sales data?

Comment: update your  question add  a proper data sample and the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the number of rows that match the company in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN company = foobar THEN sales ELSE 0 END) as sales_foobar,
       SUM(sales) as sales_total, country, year, product
FROM sales_table
GROUP BY country, year, product
HAVING SUM( company = foobar ) > 0;  -- there is at least one record for the company
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Where :

```
   SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN company=foobar THEN sales ELSE 0) as sales_foobar,
    SUM(sales) as sales_total, country, year, product 
    FROM sales_table
    Where sales > 0
    GROUP BY country, year, product HAVING (the above sum again) > 0
```

Comment: wouldn't this also omit rows where other companies do not have sales?

Answer (score 0):

Just worked out as per your question assuming company='foobar;
You had almost done the answer in your code only. So if you required any other specific criteria other than this, please let me know. I would edit the answer.

```
SELECT 
    SUM (CASE WHEN company='foobar' THEN sales ELSE 0 end) as sales_foobar,
    SUM(sales) as sales_total, 
    country, 
    year, 
    product 
        FROM sales_table
            GROUP BY country, year, product 
                HAVING SUM (CASE WHEN company='foobar' THEN sales ELSE 0 end) > 0
```

[image]

Comment: yes, i just skipped typing the case when again, but its the same in the code.

Comment: @t-c: So can you elaborate or edit your question with a good result you expect? And a sample data for same. So that I can get more clear idea what exactly you need.

Comment: i can't use the real data here, but for example:

company 1 sold 10 units, company 2 sold 10 but also refunded 10, so total is 0, and company 3 does not have any data for this specific set.

now, if i query for company 2, i should receive 0 sales with 10 total,
but for company 3 no result would be returned (so they dont get totals)

Comment: @t-c: So you mean to say Units has to be considered as sales, and Refund column should be added and  (sales - refund) data should not be zero. If zero then it should be excluded from query.